# Spinners in extended list view have mixed up values

Tags: android

I am new to android and have been googling for weeks for the solution of this problem. I have a spinner in the body, and a textfield in the head of an extended list which is in a scroll view in a fragment. The text in the header is displayed correctly, but the spinners values change as I show/hide a child view.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I would appreciate any help here.

Here is the adapter:

```
public class ExtendedListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
    private Context ctx;
    private LinkedHashMap<String, List<List<LinkedHashMap<String, String>>>> extendedListData;
    private List<String> extendedListHeaders;

    class Viewholder {
        View rowView;
        Spinner spnr;
        TextView item1;
    }
    public ExtendedListAdapter(Context ctx, LinkedHashMap<String, List<List<LinkedHashMap<String, String>>>> extendedListData, List<String> extendedListHeaders) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.extendedListData = extendedListData;
        this.extendedListHeaders = extendedListHeaders;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int parent, int child) {
        return extendedListData.get(extendedListHeaders.get(parent)).get(child);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int parent, int child) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return child;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int parentId, int childId, boolean lastChild, View convertView,
                             ViewGroup parentview) {

        Viewholder v;

        if (convertView == null) {

            v = new Viewholder();

            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.child_layout, parentview, false);

            v.rowView = convertView;
            v.rowView.setTag(v);
            v.item1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textLabel);
            v.spnr = (Spinner) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        }
        else {
            v = (Viewholder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        List<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> childListLinkedHashMap = (List<LinkedHashMap<String, String>>) getChild(parentId, childId);
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> label = childListLinkedHashMap.get(0);
        String[] items = new String[childListLinkedHashMap.size() - 1];

        v.item1.setText(label.get("name"));

        for (int i = 1; i < childListLinkedHashMap.size(); i++) {
            items[i - 1] = childListLinkedHashMap.get(i).get("name");
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(ctx, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items);

        v.spnr.setAdapter(adapter);
        if (v.spnr.getTag() != null) {
            v.spnr.setSelection((int) v.spnr.getTag());
        }
        v.spnr.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                       int position, long id) {
                parent.setTag(position);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int arg0) {

        return extendedListData.get(extendedListHeaders.get(arg0)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return extendedListHeaders.get(arg0);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return extendedListHeaders.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return arg0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int parent, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parentview) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String group_title = (String) getGroup(parent);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.parent_layout, parentview, false);
        }
        TextView parent_textview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.parent_txt);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        parent_textview.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        parent_textview.setText(group_title);
        if (isExpanded) {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.group_down);
        } else {
            imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.group_up);
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the spinner selected value, you are trying to access a tag from spinner, but you are setting the tag on `ExpandedListView` (`parent`), *not* the spinner.  But even if you fixed that, it still wouldn't work.

When the view is recycled, you will be getting the spinner value from the recycled view, which will still cause your spinners to have the wrong value as your list is scrolled.

Essentially, you are trying to store model data (the spinner selection) on the view, instead of in the model where it should be.

To make this work, you will need something like a list of lists of ints – the first list for the groups and the second list for the children.

So let's add a property for storing the selections:

```
    private int[][] selected;
```

You should be able to use arrays here, since your lists/maps don't seem to be changing in size.

Set it up in the constructor:

```
    selected = new int[extendedListHeaders.size()][];
    for (int i = 0; i < selected.length; i++) {
        int childSize = extendedListData.get(extendedListHeaders.get(i)).size();
        selected[i] = new int[childSize];
    }
```

Now your spinner logic in `getChildView` will look like this:

```
        v.spnr.setSelection(selected[parentId][childId]);

        v.spnr.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                   int position, long id) {
                selected[parentId][childId] = position;
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) { }
        });
```

You will need to make the `parentId` and `childId` parameters `final` in order to use them in the event callback.

With the event callback setting the model data and the view using the model data, the spinners should work the way you expect.

Comment: Thanks Kris, this helped. But my question was about the values of spinners, not the selected values. Here is the repo, since it is easier to see what I mean from an example: git@bitbucket.org:fermicoding/lhapp.git

Comment: The adapter values seemed like they are coming from the right place.  Unless you have duplicate header values, I don't know where the problem with the adapter values is coming from.